# Изображение в html письме на yandex.mail

Tags: html, email, изображения, svg

Вставляю svg картинку с колбеком png в html письмо. Тестил в большинстве браузеров и основных почтовых клиентах (gmail, yahoo, mail.ru, bigmir.net, yandex). Во всех отображается нормально, но в yandex картинка не отображается. 
Есть мысль, что проблема в ресурсе, который использую для отправки письма (https://elasticemail.com). Также может быть проблема в русурсах где хранятся картинки. Если так, то посоветуйте хорошие ресурсы.

```html
<a href="#" style="display:block; height:38px; width:498px;">
  <img src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/img.png"  alt="img" srcset="http://svgshare.com/img.svg" style="display:block; height:38px; width:498px;">
</a>
```

Comment: А почему бы просто не посмотреть на получившийся html-код письма  в браузере?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Яндекс ресайзит фото, при этом меняет url. Размер <img> правильного размера, но фото в нем 1х1 стало.

Comment: Не по теме: в Thunderbird, Outlook, The Bat, Android Email проверяли?

Comment: @andreymal Проверял в Outlook - все ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в том, что для отображения картинок в yandex.mail в атрибуте `src` нужно разрешить протокол «data:». Я закодировал картинку с помощью http://b64.io/, но закодированные картинки полностью удаляются из src в gmail. Для этого использовал атрибут с `src` с прямой ссылкой на `png` картинку и srcset для закодированой `svg` картинки.

```
<a href="#" style="display:block; height:38px; width:498px;">
  <img src="https://host/img.png"  alt="img" srcset="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94......3ZnPg==" style="display:block; height:38px; width:498px;">
</a>
```

Comment: Протестировал способ- gmail отображает все двоичные данный srcset прямо в письме.